# Nav Menu - Highlight choices, but not active page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to sort out creating a basic nav menu.
I created a nav menu with :hover properties for the choices in the menu.
However, I have the current page, set as an active, and I do not want the active page on the menu bar to highlight like the other choices.

I have tried every which way to get it to work with no success. Please help!

```css
/* Main Navigation Menu */
ul#main-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #336699;
}
li {
  float: right;
}
li a, .menu-drop-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* li a:hover, .menu-drop-btn:hover .menu-drop-btn{
  background-color: #6699cc;
  cursor: pointer;
} */
li a:hover, :not(.menuactive #active):hover {
  background-color: #6699cc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* #active:hover {
  background-color: #336600;
  cursor: pointer;
} */

li.menu-drop-btn {
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu-drop-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #003300;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
}
.menu-drop-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 15px 0 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.menu-dropdown:hover .menu-drop-content {
  display: block;
}
.menu-drop-content a:hover {
  background-color: #6699cc;
}
.menu-active {
  float: left;
  background-color: #336600;
}

/* Body and Background */
body {
  background-color: #ffcc80;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"  />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="main-menu">
      <li class="menu-active" id="active"><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact</a></li>
      <li class="menu-dropdown"><a class="menu-drop-btn">Portfolio</a>
          <div class="menu-drop-content">
            <a>Link 1</a>
            <a>Link 2</a>
            <a>Link 3</a>
          </div></li>
      <li><a>About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <h1>Testing testing...</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, if Contact is the active page, Home should get the hover style, etc.?

Comment: In your code snippet, no menu item is highlighting. Did you perhaps comment out the relevant css styles?

Comment: Tieson T. The idea is that The active page will float to the opposite side of the other choices, and WILL NOT highlight when hovered, while the other menu choices WILL highlight when hovered.

Comment: Matejcik, yes I had the highlighting code snippet commented out. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the `:not` filter to the list item. This seems to work:

```
li:not(#active) a:hover {
  background-color: #6699cc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The rule, when written like this, selects the hover "event" of any anchor element that is a child (a descendant) of a list item that **does not** have the ID of "active".

Like so:

```css
/* Main Navigation Menu */
ul#main-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #336699;
}
li {
  float: right;
}
li a, .menu-drop-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* This is the change that seems to work */
li:not(#active) a:hover {
  background-color: #6699cc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.menu-drop-btn {
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu-drop-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #003300;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
}
.menu-drop-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 15px 0 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.menu-dropdown:hover .menu-drop-content {
  display: block;
}
.menu-drop-content a:hover {
  background-color: #6699cc;
}
.menu-active {
  float: left;
  background-color: #336600;
}

/* Body and Background */
body {
  background-color: #ffcc80;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"  />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="main-menu">
      <li class="menu-active" id="active"><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact</a></li>
      <li class="menu-dropdown"><a class="menu-drop-btn">Portfolio</a>
          <div class="menu-drop-content">
            <a>Link 1</a>
            <a>Link 2</a>
            <a>Link 3</a>
          </div></li>
      <li><a>About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <h1>Testing testing...</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That sure did work! Thanks a lot! To clarify, when you put a space between the _li:not(#active)_ and the  _a:hover_ that means you are taking anchors that are nested within list items not ID as active? So other anchors throughout the page, may also share that same formatting unless I further specifiy in the CSS sheet?

Comment: Correct. A space makes it a descendant selector.